# Bitshifted Enum values as Constant

Tags: dart

Why are Bitwise Enum index values not allowed to be used as constants in Dart?
ie:

```
enum Foo {
  item1,
  item2,
}

enum Bar {
  item1,
  item2,
}

const fooBar = Foo.item1.index | Bar.item2.index;
```

Thank you,

Jon

Answer (score 1):

This my solution to Enum BitFlags in Dart/Flutter

```
// Mixin to create Enum for bitflags uses.
mixin BzpFlagsEnum on Enum {
  // value receive a bitwise shift operation. It means "shift the bits of 1 to the left by index places". So,  "1,10,100,1000..." == 1,2,4,8,16....
  int get value => 1 << index;
  // Creates a operator "|" for enum.
  int operator |(other) => value | other.value;
}

// Extension "int" to verify that value contains the enum flag.
extension ExtensionFlag on int {
  bool has(BzpFlagsEnum enumFlag) => this & enumFlag.value == enumFlag.value;
}



// A sample.

enum FormActions with BzpFlagsEnum {
  noAction,
  editingData,
  structureFields,
  all;
}

 int _sanabio = FormActions.editingData | FormActions.structureFields; // 6 ( 2 | 4)

 _sanabio.has(FormActions.noAction); // false
 _sanabio.has(FormActions.editingData); // true
 _sanabio.has(FormActions.all); // false
 _sanabio.has(FormActions.structureFields); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into the `Enum` class from `dart:core` you will find that the `index` is a getter, which is not compile time constant; Thus, you cannot assign it to a `const` variable.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.1/dart-core/Enum/index.html

Apparently there were opened issue to support bitwise Enums in Dart. See [#33698](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33698) (There is a workaround class provided in one of the replies) and [#158](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/158).

Comment: Thank you a7md0.  I would +1 the answer but after 8 fricking years, I ridiculously **still** only have a repitation of one  *rolls eyes*